# how to make opencart multi-store share same cart and other?

Tags: share, cart

---

my website information : 
opencart 2.0.2

### vqmod :current last.

---

databese information:

### store 1 and 2 no database.its redirect default site.(with config.php)

---

**htaccess :**

### default Store : same, store 1:same,  strore 2 :same

---

admincp:
admincp server setting : Use Shared Sessions activated.

### (SEO URLs Active : yes)

ı want to share cart and logins 
ı wait for this 4 month help me please

Answer (score 0):

Easy Solution,

1. OPEN FILE: system/library/session.php
2. FIND LINE: session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');
3. APPEND   : session_set_cookie_params(0, '/','**.DOMAIN.COM**);

Make sure to include the period **"."** before DOMAIN.COM

That's it...  Now login sessions started on **www.domain.com** is shared with **www.sub.domain.com**

Comment: Hi again.
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''.mywebsite.net);' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE) in /home/mywebsite.net/httpdocs/system/library/session.php on line 11

I don't use subdomain.ı use different domain.database same but ftp different.

Comment: please help me ?