# Opencart multi-store share cart through different domains

Tags: php, session, opencart, cart, multistore

I have an opencart website with two stores in different domains, domain1.com and domain2.com.

What I want is to be able to share the cart through them, so that if I add some product to the cart in domain1.com and I go to domain2.com I will still have those products in the cart.

I have seen something like it, but for different subdomains and I haven't found anything for different domains.
ex: [question for subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32998968/how-to-make-opencart-multi-store-share-same-cart-and-other)

I am running version 1.5.6 and the session file is this:

```
class Session {
  public $data = array();

  public function __construct() {
    if (!session_id()) {
        ini_set('session.use_cookies', 'On');
        ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 'Off');


        session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');
        session_start();
    }

    $this->data =& $_SESSION;
  }

  function getId() {
    return session_id();
  }
}
```

How could I change this file in order to share the session and the cart?

All help is welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't go through this option, and I changed to subdomains.
Unfortunately I couldn't resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is a true solution but I know that the cart details stored in "customer" table on sql. So you need to change or delete where section of every sql query which gives you the cart details.

For example delete where store_id = x section on every query.

Comment: I understand your answer, but isn't there something easier through the session variables?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you set the cookie lifetime to 0? Seems you're planning to destroy the session. You should definitely try to use something like

```
<?php
session_set_cookie_params(1800, '/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

You may need some extra validating for the HTTP_HOST, but basically it's a rather reliable variable since Apache or Nginx rely on it. Should limit it to your current hostname.